# How to specify "child of [T]" as a type in a Scala case class

Tags: scala, inheritance

Let's say I have a `Report` class and two child classes

```
class Report {
}

class SubReport extends Report {
}

class SubReport2 extends Report {
}
```

and then I have a case class, where in one of the properties (`reportType`), I want to use to specify one of the `SubReport` types

```scala
case class SubReportClient(
    reportType: Report //Using parent class
)
```

My question is, is there a keyword or construct where I can specify a 
something like `ChildOf(Report)` as a type in the case class, and it would have the type checking accept any child classes.

I have tried instantiating the case class like the below, but failed.

```scala
SubReportClient(
    classOf[SubReport]
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`case class SubReportClient(reportType: Report)` is actually correct, it will accept all subclasses of `Report`, and nothing else. Is that not what you want?

If you want access to the actual type inside the class, you could make it generic:

```
 case class SubReportClient[T <: Report)(reportType: T)
```

But this way `SubReportClient(new SubReport)` and `SubReportClient(new SubReport2)` are instances of two *different* classes.